# Whitelist IP between Web apps and SQL Server

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have a SQL Server and a Web App in the Azure. I need securing network between them. I imagine both of them are connected with specific IP address, exclusively. I think about this idea for securing and preventing Web App by cloning it.

[image]

So far, I also know about securing SQL database using [firewall](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/managed-cloud/en/ip-whitelisting-for-azure-sql-server-and-web-apps.html) and Web apps using [whitelist](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/managed-cloud/en/ip-whitelisting-for-azure-sql-server-and-web-apps.html). But these two terms don't give any exclusive IP connection between them.

So, any idea how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually in Azure SQL Server, [IP firewall rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure#use-the-azure-portal-to-manage-server-level-ip-firewall-rules) are set to ensure connection security. So I guess what you want is the following way to ensure connection security.

App Service [provides a managed identity for your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi), which is a turn-key solution for securing access to Azure SQL Database and other Azure services.

Comment: manage identity is a solution in the application side but I just found in the SQL server firewall setting by 'Deny public network access' (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-settings#deny-public-network-access>). It means in the Webapp side create 'VNet Integration' for Private Endpoint..

Answer (score 1):

I wrote below powershell script to do the job. This script will whitelist all possible outbound ip addresses of multiple web app to an azure sql server.

```
$rg = "azure-sql-resource-group-name"
$rg1 = "webapp-resource-group-name"
$sn = "sql-server-name"
$WebApps = @("webApp1","webApp2","webApp3", "webApp4") #List of web apps to be whitelisted..

    foreach($app in $WebApps ) { 
        $i = 0
        $IPs = (az webapp show --resource-group $rg1 --name $app --query possibleOutboundIpAddresses).Replace('"', '')
        foreach ($ip in $IPs -split ',' ) {
            $i = $i + 1
            $rn = $app + '-' + $i
            $o = 'Adding.. ' + $rn + ' : ' + $ip
            Write-Output $o
            az sql server firewall-rule create --name $rn --resource-group $rg --server $sn  --end-ip-address $ip --start-ip-address $ip
        }
    }
```